# move fa-bars relative to the toggled navigation menu

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I am working on designing a webpage which has a toggled navigation menu which expands on clicking the fa-bars button and collapses on clicking the same button again. I was able to successfully do that as in the following html and css

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <a id="menu-toggle" href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a> 
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Brand
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <a id="menu-toggle" href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

**CSS for sidebar**

```
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-right: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    right: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 105px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}
```

**Javascript to toggle**

```
 $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
```

The above code seems to work fine but I was trying to move the fa-bars relative to the toggled navigation instead of keeping it in the same location

right now I have the following page screenshot

[image]

in the above picture I have 3-bars button at a fixed location but I want it outside the wrapper when the navigation bar is expanded and want it at the right corner as it is in the above image when the navigation is collapsed

Comment: Can you replicate the problem with the stack snippet.

Comment: I tried replicating it at http://jsfiddle.net/VDcnr/11/ but the javascript isn't working